# How do I install the scopes of graphic design lens in 12.04?

Tags: unity, 12.04, lenses, scopes

In Ubuntu 11.10, I used a unity-lens called *graphicdesign* from `ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa`.

I installed it on both 11.10 and 12.04 with:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-graphicdesign unity-scope-colourlovers unity-scope-deviantart unity-scope-dribbble unity-scope-iconfinder
```

But in 12.04, trying to install it like I did, I find the following packages that were included are **missing** - no installation candidate found:

- unity-scope-colourlovers
- unity-scope-dribbble
- unity-scope-iconfinder

The *unity-scope-deviantart* scope installs just fine, but these other three scopes are crucial for the graphicdesign lense to be useful! Has anybody had any luck finding updates for these three packages?

**Edit**: I understand that there are no *precise* packages in the mentioned ppa; does anyone know *where* to get updates for the 3 missing packages?

Comment: You can ask “Scopes Packagers” team directly [hare](https://launchpad.net/~scopes-packagers)

Comment: Thanks @BasharatSial, I sent them a enquiry from the ppa page. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PPA packages should be updated in a few hours to work on Precise. 
Please file a bug on https://bugs.launchpad.net/onehundredscopes if you find any issues I could have missed during the testing.

Sorry about the delay, enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

These three packages haven't updated for Precise (12.04) yet.

- unity-scope-colourlovers
- unity-scope-dribbble
- unity-scope-iconfinder

Where as `unity-scope-deviantart` is updated so that's why it's working for you.

Screenshot from official Launchpad page:

[image]

Official Launchpad page: [“Scopes Packagers” team](https://launchpad.net/~scopes-packagers/+archive/ppa)

Answer (score 0):

According to this: http://iloveubuntu.net/easy-guide-ubuntu-1204s-unity-lenses you need to install unity-scope-deviantart as well. i.e.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-graphicdesign unity-scope-deviantart
```

It installed fine on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for replying, yes the deviantart scope installed and is working but the other three that _were_ working in 11.10 are no longer working in 12.04.

If you are using 12.04, can you verify that you are seeing 4 scopes in the graphicdesign lense?  

* Palettes 
* Icons 
* Brushes 
* Design

Comment: I'm sorry. I misunderstood your question. I thought you were saying those were unfilled dependencies, not allowing you to install unity-lens-graphicdesign. Looks like you just needed a little more patience. :-)